# Converting .sql insert table file to excel

Tags: mysql, excel, vba

I have several files with the extension .sql that are all formatted in the same way. I'd like to convert them to a usable format in excel (csv, a table or anything really). I do have a very big hurdle though, I cannot set up a MySQL server as I'm not a programmer and have IT restrictions. Similarly I can't install any applications as workarounds here.

With that out of the way, all my SQL code is in the same format:

```sql
--
-- Table structure for table `cruises`
--

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `cruises`;
CREATE TABLE `cruises` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `project` varchar(32) DEFAULT NULL,
  `itinerary_id` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `title` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ship_name` varchar(64) DEFAULT NULL,
  `duration` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `departure_port` varchar(64) DEFAULT NULL,
  `departure_time` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `inside` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
  `oceanview` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
  `balcony` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
  `suite` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
  `studio` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `spa` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `haven` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `is_lowest_price` tinyint(1) DEFAULT '0',
  `create_time` timestamp NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `unique` (`project`,`itinerary_id`,`title`,`ship_name`,`duration`,`departure_port`,`departure_time`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=28076 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

--
-- Dumping data for table `cruises`


LOCK TABLES `cruises` WRITE;
INSERT INTO `cruises` VALUES (22625,'disneycruise','10_europe_copenhagen_dover','10-Night Northern Europe Cruise from Copenhagen to Dover','Disney Magic',10,'Copenhagen','2017-06-18 00:00:00',6805,7585,10585,30585,0,0,0,0,'2016-05-14 10:15:19'),(22634,'disneycruise','10_mediteranean_barcelona','10-Night Mediterranean Cruise from Barcelona','Disney Magic',10,'Barcelona','2017-07-28 00:00:00',6556,7856,10456,31456,0,0,0,0,'2016-05-14 10:15:19')
```

I've tried using online converters (CodeBeautify) and another but I have over 12,000 lines so they are not going to work. Additionally, splitting up the data isn't really an option due to the formatting they require (insert table statements for each piece) and due to time constraints.

I've written a macro where you paste the entire SQL file into excel. It has issues because when I copy and paste the SQL into excel it's very brittle because it uses the text-to-columns settings so I have to be extremely careful with them. Additionally because the entire 12,000 line SQL insert table statement is on one line, excel just drops entire sections of the data. Most of my macro is about manipulating what does get copied so that it gets into table form. It definitely works with smaller data samples, but it doesn't scale well for the reasons just stated. Also, I'm doing some pretty sketchy hookups to this specific data dump, this wouldn't work for a generic create table file.

```vb
Sub SQLtoExcelConverter()
'Paste your SQL from Apple's Cruise Center into A1 of the Input sheet.

Dim OutputData As Worksheet
Dim SQLData As Worksheet
Set OutputData = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Output")
Set SQLData = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Input")

'Find out the rows in which the headers for the SQL data are residing
titleRowStart = SQLData.Columns.Find("CREATE TABLE").Row + 1
titleRowEnd = SQLData.Columns.Find("PRIMARY KEY").Row - 1

'Places headers on the Output Page
For i = titleRowStart To titleRowEnd
    OutputData.Cells(1, i + 1 - titleRowStart).Formula = "=MID(Input!A" & i & ", FIND(""`"",Input!A" & i & ")+1, FIND(""`"", Input!A" & i & ", FIND(""`"", Input!A" & i & ")+1)-FIND(""`"",Input!A" & i & ")-1)"
    OutputData.Cells(1, i + 1 - titleRowStart).Value = OutputData.Cells(1, i + 1 - titleRowStart).Value
Next i

'Finds the Rows where thetable data is sorted. Extremely sketch code here
dataRowstart = SQLData.Columns.Find("INSERT INTO", SearchOrder:=xlByColumns).Row
dataRowEnd = SQLData.Columns.Find("/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `cruises` ENABLE KEYS */;").Row - 1

'Cleans the data
SQLData.Range("A" & dataRowstart & ":A" & dataRowEnd).Select
'Removes the initial table setting
Selection.Replace What:="INSERT INTO `cruises` VALUES (", Replacement:="", _
    LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat _
    :=False, ReplaceFormat:=False
'Replaces the delimiter between rows by a strange character char(19) since excel needs a 1 character delimiter
ch1 = Chr(19)
Selection.Replace What:="),(", Replacement:=ch1, LookAt:=xlPart, _
    SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
    ReplaceFormat:=False
'Starts the separation process
Selection.TextToColumns Destination:=Range("A" & dataRowstart), DataType:=xlDelimited, _
    TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=False, _
    Semicolon:=False, Comma:=False, Space:=False, Other:=True, OtherChar _
    :=ch1, TrailingMinusNumbers:=True
'Heals data that was chopped in the inital copy into the spreadsheet
For i = dataRowstart + 1 To dataRowEnd
    SQLData.Cells(i, 1).Value = Chr(39) & SQLData.Cells(i, 1)
    SQLData.Cells(i - 1, FindNextEmpty(SQLData.Cells(i - 1, 1)).Column - 1).Value = SQLData.Cells(i - 1, FindNextEmpty(SQLData.Cells(i - 1, 1)).Column - 1).Value & SQLData.Cells(i, 1).Value
    SQLData.Cells(i, 1).Delete Shift:=xlShiftToLeft
Next i

'Copies all the data over to the Output page
SQLData.Rows(dataRowstart & ":" & dataRowEnd).Select
i = 2
For Each c In Selection
    If Not IsEmpty(c) Then
        OutputData.Cells(i, 1).Value = c.Value
        i = i + 1
    End If
Next c

'Splits all the data again by commas
OutputData.Range("A2:A" & ColumnLength("A", OutputData)).TextToColumns Destination:=Range("A2"), DataType:=xlDelimited, _
    TextQualifier:=xlSingleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=False, _
    Semicolon:=False, Comma:=True, Space:=False, Other:=False, OtherChar:= _
    ch2, TrailingMinusNumbers:=True

'Resets TextToColumns settings so that the next copy-paste isn't messed up
SQLData.Range("I1").Value = 1
SQLData.Range("I1").TextToColumns Destination:=Range("I1"), DataType:=xlDelimited, _
        TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=False, _
        Semicolon:=False, Comma:=False, Space:=False, Other:=False, OtherChar _
        :="~", FieldInfo:=Array(1, 1), TrailingMinusNumbers:=True
y = FindNextEmpty(OutputData.Cells(1, 1)).Column - 1
OutputData.Cells(OutputData.Cells(Rows.Count, y).End(xlUp).Row, y).Replace What:=");", Replacement:="", _
    LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat _
    :=False, ReplaceFormat:=False

MsgBox "If your data came out all wrong it's possible the text to columns settings were tampered with. Try recopying your data and running the macro again."
End Sub

Public Function FindNextEmpty(ByVal rCell As Range) As Range
'Finds the first empty cell downwards in a column.



With rCell
   'If the start cell is empty it is the first empty cell.
   If Len(.Formula) = 0 Then
      Set FindNextEmpty = rCell
      'If the cell just below is empty
   ElseIf Len(.Offset(0, 1).Formula) = 0 Then
      Set FindNextEmpty = .Offset(0, 1)
   Else
      'Finds the last cell with content.
      '.End(xlDown) is like pressing CTRL + arrow down.
      Set FindNextEmpty = .End(xlToRight).Offset(0, 1)
   End If
End With
End Function
Public Function ColumnLength(Column As String, ByVal WS As Worksheet) As Long

ColumnLength = WS.Cells(Rows.Count, Column).End(xlUp).Row


End Function
```

Comment: @c g - the best way is to import them in a database and then export it or change the STORAGE ENGINE TO CSV. If it not to much and also not secret data in you can zip them and send me. i will change quickly for you,

Comment: Have a look at something like this [mysqldump-to-csv](https://github.com/jamesmishra/mysqldump-to-csv)

Comment: @BerndBuffen Unfortunately I'm setting up a weekly process so a 1 time fix won't really help. Thank you though.

Comment: @Tom My issue still remains that this is a corporate computer with many restrictions as such we don't even have python installed (I should have mentioned that I read that page already). Do you think it would be feasible to mimic that python code in VBA? (I have some experience with python).

Comment: @c g -  i have testet the comment from Tom and the output looks nice. It easy to install and using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try something like this

```
Sub ImportMySQLDumptoExcel()
    Dim intF As Integer
    Dim i As Long
    Dim vSql() As String, strSql As String, temp As String
    Dim vSqls As Variant, tempArr As Variant

    intF = FreeFile()
    ' Set this to your .sql file path
    Open "SQLDUMPFILEPATH" For Input As #intF
    strSql = Input(LOF(intF), #intF)
    Close intF
    vSql = Split(strSql, ";")

    ' Row Counter
    i = 1

    For Each vSqls In vSql
        If InStr(1, vSqls, "Values (", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
            temp = Trim(Right(vSqls, Len(vSqls) - (InStr(1, vSqls, "Values (", vbTextCompare) + 7)))
            temp = Trim(Left(temp, Len(temp) - 1))
            temp = Replace(temp, "'", "")
            tempArr = Split(temp, ",")

            ' Change this to where you want your results to go
            With Sheet1
                Range(.Cells(i, 1), .Cells(i, UBound(tempArr))) = tempArr
                i = i + 1
            End With
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

This is something I've knocked together very quickly. It will open your sql file and read each line that contains `VALUES (` and then try to clean the line.

This could be particular to the sql file and could need some modification to work in your case. Let me know how you get on with it

I used the example `world.sql` world database from here: [MySQL World Database](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/index-other.html) to write this.

This will populate all the cells in your excel sheet as strings so you may have to add in some handling for different data types (e.g. integers)

Comment: This should help with copy-paste issues that excel has. I'm currently debugging to see why it's not pasting my data correctly but it's definitely a solid start. I got this to work by rewriting the portion where I want the results. I also changed the split on tempArr to "),(" and then got each row I wanted which I will then process again (splitting by commas), for this reason I also didn't replace the quotes. Very nicely done!

Comment: As I said it might have needed some mods for your sql files but glad it helped

Comment: I was going through one of your recent post and tried for my case. I have few .sql files at the path "c:\Excelvba_exp\sql\". If I give the codeline as `Open "c:\Excelvba_exp\sql\" For Input As #intF` I get error 76 but if I put `"c:\Excelvba_exp\sql\*.sql"` I get error 52. Please guide me to the correct syntax to be used . For this minor point , A new question may not be appropriate.

Comment: This is due to the code is expecting a file not a directory/load of files. You'll need to stick this in a loop and loop through each file in the directory