# Import script into Excel and split by ;

Tags: sql, excel, vba

I have a folder with scripts with around 10 insert statements in each.

Is there a way to import all these scripts into an Excel spreadsheet (not the script names but the contents) and have them separated by the delimiter ; so one insert statement per cell?

Comment: Are these .sql files or a different data type?

Comment: these are all .sql files apologies

Comment: Sure, and why are you wanting to stick these all into Excel? If you're trying to transfer them somewhere or email then I'd just zip the folder up and send that.

Comment: I'm not trying to transfer them anywhere, i just need a breakdown. I can obviously do this manually but theres around 50 scripts.

Comment: Are the scripts already delimited by ";"?

Comment: yes the scripts are fully working insert functions all separated by ";" , i just want to be able to run something which takes these scripts and separates into rows based on the delimiter

Comment: Use a `Scripting.FileSystemObject` to `ReadAll` the data in a file, and `Split` it into an array of statements using the `;` delimiter.  Write the array into the excel spreadsheet.  Should do it fairly easily?

Comment: thanks dave, will give this a go cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should get you started. Read your string into the split statement (I've just mocked this up using the values in cell `A1` of `Sheet1` of a new work book. This then prints all the values split to the second row.

Combine this with Dave's comment above and you should have your solution

```
Sub SplitStatements()
    Dim NoOfStatements

    With Sheet1
        NoOfStatements = Len(.Cells(1, 1)) - Len(Replace(.Cells(1, 1), ";", ""))
        .Range(.Cells(2, 1), .Cells(2, NoOfStatements + 1)) = Split(.Cells(1, 1), ";")
    End With
End Sub
```

[image]

**Update: Full solution**

```
Sub SplitSQLStatements()
    Dim intF As Integer
    Dim vSql() As String, strSql As String
    Dim NoOfStatements As Long

    intF = FreeFile()
    ' Set this to your .sql file path
    Open "SQLDUMPFILEPATH" For Input As #intF
    strSql = Input(LOF(intF), #intF)
    Close intF
    vSql = Split(strSql, ";")

    With Sheet1
        NoOfStatements = UBound(vSql) + 1
        .Range(.Cells(2, 1), .Cells(2, NoOfStatements)) = vSql
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: If you have any issues just ping me on here

Comment: I can use and understand your code fine, i had something similar to the above doing the same thing, its just pulling the text from a file that i dont have a clue about!

Comment: This is an answer I gave a while a go that does similar [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37422598/converting-sql-insert-table-file-to-excel/37434013#37434013). The for loop is just there to clean some of the data. Remove that part and print the array to your range

Comment: I've just combined the two. Update the necessary bits and see how you get on

Comment: Thanks Tom! I will give it ago now,

Comment: omg i actually got it to work, (i know i shouldnt be surprised as you've given me pretty much all the answers but hella yeah man super pleased!) the only issues i have now is where i specify the path, im having to use the exact file path so the file name .sql how would i change this to just run through the folder?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116678/discussion-between-tom-and-benji-taylor).